# By what mechanism does the reaction between NCl3 (Nitrogen Trichloride) and NOCl (Nitrosyl Chloride) occur?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

The reaction produces 2 Cl2 and 1 N2O. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

One can rarely be sure when it comes to inorganic reactions, but I think that this would be a reasonable mechanism:
[image]

There are also other possibilities.